# How to store dropdown value in database and display selected when edit item?

Tags: magento-2.1, module, database, crud

I am developing custom module. Other fields are saving data in database but i have issue with Dropdown field. It's not saving value in database. My code as following:

```
$elements['target'] = $fieldset->addField(
        'target',
        'select',
        [
            'name' => 'target',
            'label' => __('Link Target'),
            'title' => __('Select target of slide item\'s link'),
            'required' => true,
            'options' => $model->getLinkTargetOptions()
        ]
    );
```

In the model file

```
public function getLinkTargetOptions()
{
    return [
        '_self' => __('Self'),
        '_blank' => __('Blank'),  
    ];
}
```

Above code adding Dropdown in the admin form. I don't know how to store it's value.

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to Create model for your custom table collection
2. Retrieve Custom table data into your `getLinkTargetOptions()` function
   and add that option data into your option array.
3. If you want to store selected option value into your custom table then after save event you can store selected data into your table.